# How do I transfer varibles through functions in Python

Tags: python, variables

I am trying to read from keyboard a number and validate it

This is what I have but it doesn't work.

No error but it doesn't **remember** the number I introduced

```
def IsInteger(a):
    try:
        a=int(a)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False 

def read():
    a=input("Nr: ")
    while (IsInteger(a)!=True):
        a=input("Give a number: ")

a=0
read()
print(a)
```

Comment: `a` the global and `a` the local name in `read()` are *separate variables*. You already seem to know how to use `return`, why not use that in `read()`?

Comment: `return` the number from `read` and reassign `a` to the returned value

Answer (score 1):

`a` is a local variable to the two functions and isn't visible to the rest of your code as is.  The best way to fix your code is by returning `a` from your `read()` function.  Also, the spacing is off in your `IsInteger()` function.

```
def IsInteger(b):
    try:
        b=int(b)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False 

def read():
    a=input("Nr: ")
    while not IsInteger(a):
        a=input("Give a number: ")
    return a

c = read()
print(c)
```

Comment: A better way to write that `while` line is `while not IsInteger(a)`. Generally, it's best to avoid explicitly testing against `True` or `False`. See [PEP-0008 Programming Recommendations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations), "Don't compare boolean values to True or False using ==". Also, in the `try` block you don't need to do that assignment, `int(b)` by itself will work fine; OTOH, I guess that may be a bit baffling to some readers. :)

Comment: @PM2Ring Good points. I've edited in the `while not IsInteger(a)` solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve.

```
def IsInteger(a):
    try:
        a=int(a)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False 

def read():
    global a
    a=input("Nr: ")
    while (IsInteger(a)!=True):
        a=input("Give a number: ")

a=0
read()
print(a)
```

You need to use `global` expression in order to overwrite the global variable without a need to create `return` inside the function and typing `a = read()`.

But I would **highly** recommend u to **use** the `return` and re-assigned the value of 'a', as someone stated below.

Comment: While this will work, using global variables is generally considered to be a bad solution in Python.

Comment: I know. That's why I just added my opinion, that he should use the re-assign way with `return`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though you are not returning the result of the read() function.

The last line of your read function should be "return a"

And then when you call the read function you would say "a = read()"